# Не получается выполнить команду gulp browser-sync в терминале

Tags: gulp, browsersync

Воспользовался кодом, предоставленным на оф сайте browsersync

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});
```

Набрал в терминале gulp browser-sync , но выскочило вот такое модальное окно и ошибка в терминале:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните, пожалуйста, максимально доходчиво (впервые пробую прикрутить эту утилиту) как решить эту проблему.

Comment: {

"port": 3000,

"server": {

"baseDir": "."

},

"browser": ["chrome"]

}

Comment: Не совсем понял, с каким синтаксисом вставлять этот кусок кода

Comment: browserSync.init(...тут...)

Comment: Открылся браузер с Cannot GET /

Comment: значит дальше уже с приложением разбирайтесь или версией build/develop

Comment: Если вы о совместимости версий-то проверил,все сходится